# Can't connect to TOR due to DisableNetwork is set

Tags: network-configuration

```
23/11/2016 16:07:24.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
23/11/2016 16:07:24.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
23/11/2016 16:07:24.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
23/11/2016 16:07:24.000 [WARN] Tor cannot connect to the Internet if ReachableAddresses, ReachableORAddresses, or ReachableDirAddresses reject all addresses. Please accept some addresses in these options. 
23/11/2016 16:07:24.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
23/11/2016 16:07:24.000 [WARN] Tor cannot connect to the Internet if ReachableAddresses, ReachableORAddresses, or ReachableDirAddresses reject all addresses. Please accept some addresses in these options. 
23/11/2016 16:07:24.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
23/11/2016 16:07:24.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
23/11/2016 16:07:26.700 [WARN] The https proxy sent back an unexpected status code 503 ("Service Unavailable"). Closing. 
23/11/2016 16:07:26.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 62.210.129.246:443 
23/11/2016 16:08:40.800 [WARN] The https proxy sent back an unexpected status code 503 ("Service Unavailable"). Closing. 
23/11/2016 16:08:40.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.50.191.95:443 
23/11/2016 16:10:11.500 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
23/11/2016 16:10:46.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
23/11/2016 16:10:46.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
23/11/2016 16:10:46.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
23/11/2016 16:10:46.800 [WARN] Tor cannot connect to the Internet if ReachableAddresses, ReachableORAddresses, or ReachableDirAddresses reject all addresses. Please accept some addresses in these options. 
23/11/2016 16:10:47.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: You've told it to use proxy servers, the proxy servers are reporting errors trying to connect to Tor and you have restricted reachable addresses. You should review your Tor Network settings.

Comment: @canonizing // Yes, unfortunately, where I am, the only way to connect to the Internet is through a proxy.  Surprisingly, it has been working fine for years with the same configuration, but suddenly it stopped working yesterday.  Does this mean settings have been changed on the proxy?

Comment: It seems likely. They're returning `503` errors which is the [`Service Unavailable` code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) but it'd definitely a problem with the proxies or someone else who is in a position to be a man-in-the-middle, since HTTP proxies are entirely transparent and unauthenticated.